# Django - Reading from Oracle database and writing to SQLite

Tags: python, django, database, oracle, sqlite

I have configured settings.py already to have two databases: an existing Oracle database, and SQLite. I am new to Django, so I hope someone can give me a detailed answer.
I want to create an app that takes specifc data from the existing Oracle database. Let us say I want to access the Oracle table called STUDENTS that has three columns: ID, NAME, and GRADE. I want to take the grades of each student and calculate the GPA of each student. Then I want to insert the GPA as a property of a new table (RESULTS) with columns: ID, NAME, GPA. But I want to store RESULTS table in the SQLite database. So I am using Oracle for reading, and SQLite for writing the new table.

How can this be done in Django?

Comment: On the Oracle side, there are some (old) resources that may help: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/python_django/python_django.htm and https://developer.oracle.com/dsl/vasiliev-django.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django already supports using multiple databases

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

You just need to use the `using=<db name>` and set the DBs up in `settings.py` to do it.

SO you could query one, and use the results to write to another.